# GNU Sed breaks with tab a a delimiter?

Tags: linux, sed

I am wondering what is going wrong here. Using a space as a delimiter works but with a tab it seems to fail.

```
% sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.8
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jay Fenlason, Tom Lord, Ken Pizzini,
Paolo Bonzini, Jim Meyering, and Assaf Gordon.

This sed program was built without SELinux support.

GNU sed home page: <https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <https://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-sed@gnu.org>.
% sed "s ^ foo " <<<hi
foohi
% sed "s\t^\tfoo\t" <<<hi
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'
```

Why doesn't a tab character work as a delimiter. I can confirm that the tab escape sequence is being expanded properly.

```
% echo sed "s\t^\tfoo\t" | cat -vT
sed s^I^^Ifoo^I
```

Comment: "I can confirm that the tab escape sequence is being expanded properly" – It is, by your `echo`. My guess is your `echo` is the Zsh's `echo` (is your shell Zsh?) that behaves more like `echo -e` of Bash. Your issue with `sed` does not involve `echo`, so the behavior of the latter is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You passed `\` as the delimiter, not the tab character.

```
sed 's\ stuff \ otherstuff \' <<<' stuff '
```

`t` is unknown flag to `s` command, hence the error

```
sed "s\t^\tfoo\t"
     ^            - command
       ^^         - regex
      ^  ^    ^   - delimiter
          ^^^^    - replacement string
               ^  - invalid flag to `s` command.
```

> Why doesn't a tab character work as a delimiter

It does - pass the literal tab character, not two characters `\` and `t`

```
sed $'s\t^\tfoo\t' <<<hi
# or
tab=$(printf '\t')
sed "s/${tab}^${tab}foo%{tab}" <<<hi
```

> I can confirm that the tab escape sequence

You can confirm that **when using echo** in your shell then **echo** replaces `\t` sequences into a tab. This does not affect `sed` in any way. You can pass the result of echo to sed, for example.

```
# will work in zsh without BSD_ECHO option
sed "$(echo 's\t^\tfoo\t')" <<<hi
# to be portable use printf
sed "$(printf 's\t^\tfoo\t')" <<<hi
```

See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html .

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that echo was parsing escape sequences. One can run `/bin/echo sed "s\t^\tfoo\t"` and see that it outputs `sed s\t^\tfoo\t`.

Answer (score 0):

Not all versions of sed understand `\t`.

Solutions from the post
[Why is sed not recognizing \t as a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610115/why-is-sed-not-recognizing-t-as-a-tab):

- Insert a literal tab : Press
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Create a variable containing a tab character using
  `TAB=$'\t'` and use it as `{TAB}`
- Put a dollar sign in front of a single quoted string :
  `sed $'s\t^\tfoo\t'`